# Create table using a variable name in the BigQuery UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a BigQuery script that I can store as a procedure, I would like one of the arguments I pass to be used in the table name that is written out by the script, for example:

```
DECLARE id STRING;
SET id = '123';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.id AS(
SELECT * FROM dataset.table
)
```

However, in this example the table is created with the name `id` rather than the value of the "id" variable, `123`. Is there any way I can dynamically create a table using the value of a declared variable in the BigQuery UI?

Comment: You cannot do this with BigQuery scripting right now. It may be supported in the future in the form of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, please monitor BigQuery release notes.

Comment: you can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with Concat(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far we have officially announced [BigQuery scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) document, which is still in Beta phase, leveraging usage of dynamic parameters (variables) as a placeholders for values in SQL queries . However, according to [Parameterized queries in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_named-web) documentation, query parameters can't be used for SQL object identifiers:

> Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column
>   names, table names, or other parts of the query.

Answer (score 14):

Why not just use Execute Immediate with `concat` if you know the table schema?

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', id, '` (column_name STRING)');
```

Comment: This is perfect and sidesteps the lack of dynamic beautifully. 
Worth noting you can use the FORMAT functionality. 
```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format('CREATE TABLE `%s` (column_name STRING)' , id); ```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can [use a wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). You would create a wildcard table with all subtables you want to query and use the `WHERE` clause to select any subtable you want. Just be careful, the tables must have the same schema.