# is it possible to do "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE foo_{@run_time|"%Y%m%d"} AS" in a scheduled query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wondering if/how i can run a CTAS type statement via a scheduled query but wrangle the @run_date or @run_time param to be the yyyymmdd suffix of the table i want to create or replace.

So the scheduled query would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE foo_{@run_date|"%Y%m%d"} AS
select 'hello'
```

Such that if i was to run it on date of '2021-07-01' i would create the table called `foo_20210701`

I'm just not quite sure for to wrangle the default @run_date param to include it in my table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59388900/6268118) and in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_named-web):

> Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column names, table names, or other parts of the query.

There is however a workaround. You could use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) to run a SQL script defined as a string. Eg.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT CURRENT_DATE()"
```

Although it is very hacky it could be used like this achieve what you need.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `some_project.some_dataset.foo_', CURRENT_DATE(), '` AS SELECT "hello" as column_name' );
```

And below an approach using a [DECLARE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) statement to keep the table name as a variable

```
DECLARE table_name STRING DEFAULT CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS STRING);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `some_project.some_dataset.foo_', table_name, '` AS SELECT "hello" as column_name' );
```