# Can I use variable in the from clause in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use a variable inside the from clause. I did the following with no success:

```
declare data_set_set STRING default 'my_data_set';
declare table_name_set STRING default 'my_table_name';
```

```
  select column_name,
         data_type
    from data_set_set.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
   where table_name = table_name_set
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create table using a variable name in the BigQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372469/create-table-using-a-variable-name-in-the-bigquery-ui)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#declare